# react-native realm : Initial data upon app installation/update?

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, realm

My app idea will have many rows of texts to use like a dictionary. Is it possible in Realm to have seed data where the data in the app is static and you can't change it other than myself when I manually edit it?

For example if I download a dictionary app, then that app is going to come with data (words and it's definitions) that I can't change. And the devs of that app can periodically add new definitions of words or fix typos when giving out updates and user would see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a Realm file offline and bundling it with your app. You bundle a Realm file by copying to the Resources directory in a `Copy Files Build Phase`, or by putting it in the `assets` directory on android. Once you have bundled a Realm file with your app, you can either open it read-only in place, or made a read-write copy by copying it to your data directory by calling `Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles()` at launch with copies all bundled Realm files for you.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused.
Where do I find the Resources directory and what is a `Copy Files Build Phase`?

Comment: This is in your project settings in your xcode project - I was assuming you are building for ios. If building on android you would need to put the file in the assets directory, after which calling `Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles()` should still work.